# How insert rows with max(order_field) + 1 transactionally in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to insert in a PostgreSQL table a row with a column containing the max value + 1 for this same column on a subset of the rows of the table. That column is used to ordering the rows in that subset.

I´m trying to update the column value in an after insert trigger but I´m obtaining duplicate values for this column in different rows.

What´s the best way to do that avoiding duplicate values for the ordering column in the subset in a concurrent environment with a lot of inserts in a short time?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: 
The subset is defined by another column of the same table: this column has the same value for all the related rows.

Comment: How is the subset defined?

Comment: Can you have gaps in the subset? Say 3, 200, 210...

Comment: I prefer not to have gaps, but this could be subsanable

Comment: I have never heard the term "register" in combination with a relational database. What exactly do you mean with that? (Btw: tables have columns, not fields)

Comment: The use of the term "field" is only a confusion because ultimately it is a jee application with JPA mapping. Respect to the use of "register", it refers to each row of the table.

Answer (score 2):

If that column is used only for ordering then use a sequence:

```
create table t (
    column1 integer,
    ordering_column serial
);
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-TABLE

Comment: The order is defined independently for each subset. The first subset has [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], the second subset has [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and if we insert later a new register related to first subset, its order field must have 9 value. With a serial column, I have an autoincremental field for all the table registers.

Comment: @vferrer And what is the problem? It will order correctly inside each subset.

Comment: This is true but... the gaps will be huge :( I was trying to do it maintaining the values as closest as possible

Comment: @vferrer Although aesthetically unpleasant it is bullet proof, very cheap and maintenance free.

Comment: I will analyse it... you´re right, it is a maintenance free method despite being ugly

Answer (score 0):

**New transactional-safe answer:**

To make it in a transactional-safe way you could use this trigger, which creates sequences for each different "set_id" value:

```
create or replace function calculate_index() returns trigger 
as $$
declare my_indexer_name text;
begin
   my_indexer_name = 'my_indexer_name_' || NEW.my_set_id;
   if NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pg_class WHERE relname = my_indexer_name)
   then
       execute 'create sequence ' || my_indexer_name;
   end if;
   select nextval(my_indexer_name) into NEW.my_index;
   return new;
end
$$
language plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER my_indexer_trigger 
     BEFORE INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
     EXECUTE PROCEDURE calculate_index();
```

Also you could create manually sequences named 'my_indexer_name_1', 'my_indexer_name_2', etc. if your set_id possible values are known beforehand, then you could eliminate the if-then from the trigger function above.

**This was my initial and not transactional-safe answer:**

I would create a new helper table let's call it set_indexes:

```
create table set_indexes( set_id integer, max_index integer );
```

each record has the set_id and the max index value of that set. e.g.:

```
 set_id,    max_index
 1          53
 2          12
 3          43
```

in the trigger code you would:

```
select max_index + 1 from set_indexes where set_indexes.set_id = NEW.my_set_id
   into NEW.my_index;
// Chek if the set_id is new:
if NEW.my_index is null then
   insert into set_indexes( set_id, max_index) values (NEW.my_set_id, 1);
   NEW.my_index = 0;
else
   update set_indexes set max_index = NEW.my_index where set_indexes.set_id = NEW.my_set_id;
end if;
```

Comment: Just a question: in a trigger, will be that select into clause transactional? Will it avoid select the same value for two concurrent registers for the same subset? In my last test, with a select into variable and a later update, I was duplicated values. In that test I didn´t have a secondary table for store the last value in each subset, I was calculating it from my main table