# How to insert row with MAX(number) + 1 in PostgreSQL transactionally without sequence

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table that can be simplified as this:

```
CREATE TABLE car(
  garage_id uuid,
  number integer
);
```

I need that in each garage, each car has a unique integer number (Car N°1, Car N°2).

**First idea with sequence**

My first idea was to create a PostgreSQL sequence for each garage thanks to a trigger, and then when I insert a car, I just need to call nextval on the sequence created for the garage. (Like seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23278147/6719814))

The problem is that for each garage, I need to create a sequence. My garage table will soon grow up to 1M rows, and according to this thread: [Maximum number of sequences that can be created](http://www.postgresql-archive.org/Maximum-number-of-sequences-that-can-be-created-td5702746.html), too much PostgreSQL sequence can really hurt performance and make pgdump fails.

**Second Idea**

I found another idea [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23278147/6719814).

The second idea was to create another table like

```
CREATE TABLE garage_number(
  garage_id uuid,
  max_number integer
);
```

This table would keep the max car number, and then at each insert we select the max_number of the garage, and update the max_number of the garage.

**Problem:** For the moment it does not work in terms of concurrency (2 cars can have the same number if inserted at the same time).

Do you have any idea of how I can make this be transaction-proof and work at scale? Maybe locking the garage_number table?

Thank you very much for your help,

Comment: "*transaction-proof and work at scale*" - you can't have both of them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know that we can't have best of both world, I just wanted to know if there is a best practice to achieve this kind of thing. Seems that's it's a common problem and I haven't found any great solution... How can we be sure that when inserting a new car, its number is unique? It's what matters most for us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*how I can make this be transaction-proof and work at scale*" - you can't. The best bet is to minimize the locking that is needed when you generate the numbers via the non-sequence approach.

Your `garage_number` table can be used for that, however I wouldn't actually use the `max()` on the actual garage table, but rather something like this:

```
create or replace function next_car_number(p_garage uuid)
  returns integer
as
$$
  update garage_number
     set max_number = max_number + 1
  where garage_id = p_garage
  returning max_number;
$$
language sql;
```

Of course you would need to initialize the `garage_number` once, and you also need to insert a new row into that table each time a new garage is created (with a value of `0` for `max_number`)

Then to assign a new car number, you can use something like this:

```
insert into car 
  (garage, number)
values 
  ('a0ee-bc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9-bd38-0a11', next_car_number('a0ee-bc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9-bd38-0a11'));
```

The row for that garage will be locked until that insert is committed and no other insert using the same function can finish until then. Once that is committed any waiting transaction will see the new value.

You need to generate (and know) the UUID for the garage *before* you insert a new car - but I guess as there is another table named `garage` that is referenced by the `car` table, the garage PK is already know when inserting a new car.

This still serializes access to the "generator" for a single garage, but will be faster then running a `max()` query for each insert

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's exactly the part I was missing. It works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't insert several cars in one transaction, maybe it's worth of trying the `txid_current()`?.. The number would be isolated from other transactions and would be unique. The only obvious but here - it would not be sequential (you cant predict the step, as it depends on amount of transactions while you perform yours).

smth like:

```
insert into car 
  (garage, number)
values 
  ('a0ee-bc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9-bd38-0a11', txid_current());
```

Of course it will not work if you run the above statement several times in same transaction, as `txid_current()` would be same. But if you separate each insert - this might work

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html